# A puzzle about two coins of total value of 15 cents, one of which is not a nickel. Is it correct at all?

Tags: mathematics, coins

The puzzle:

> In my pocket, I have two US coins of total value of 15 cents. One of my coins is NOT a nickel. What are the coins?

A mathematician told me that I was totally wrong when I posted my solution (one coin, a dime; another one, a nickel). The mathematician wrote:

> You are totally wrong! A dime and a nickel is a deceiving answer which you should never give. The truth is we were given a piece of information about just ONE coin. They told us: 'One coin is NOT a nickel.' So we know absolutely nothing about the other one! It may also be NOT a nickel as well as the first one.

I analyzed his observation and it's essentially true. Indeed, they told us a bit of information referring to one coin only. Absolutely no information about the other one.
So is he right?

Furthermore, he made another strange observation. He said it's a mathematical problem and not an economical one. Thus, children aren't obliged to know US coin denominations, so 3 and 12 cents is a totally correct answer. And so is 4 and 11 cents. And so on.

Is this problem a good puzzle at all?

Personally I consider it extremely simple but very, very good. For a child, of course. But an adult can enjoy it too. It was very strange to hear such words from a professional mathematician.

Comment: I guess the mathematician is of the ilk who knows the exact volume of a jar, but not how to open it. Obviously, they are completely unfamiliar with money. And logic too. I quite liked the puzzle – I did have to think for a moment! The mathematician IMO is wrong to say "the other coin might not be a nickel too" because if that is true then there can't be any solution. The other coin *must* be a nickel.

Comment: I have a mathematics degree from Cambridge University, and this "mathematician" is a pillock.

Comment: The "one of the coins is not a nickel" part is completely redundant. If you need two US coins that total 15 cents, there is only one possible answer, and that's for one of the coins to be a dime instead of a nickel. The mathematician is just rules-lawyering in an obnoxious manner.

Comment: @F1Krazy saying "one of the coins is not a nickel" is what makes it a (simple) puzzle, rather than a math exercise.

Comment: The part about knowing nothing about the other coin is a bit…weird? Like, if the rule _specifically_ states that _one_ of the coins is not a nickel, one can assume that the others can.

Comment: "In my pocket, I have two US coins".  This is plenty of information about the other coin.  And no, US coins don't come in 11 or 12 cent denominations.

Comment: @FlorianF a *[dim-wit term]* forger goes into a bar and asks the barman "Can you change this 18 dollar bill for me?" "Sure, would you like two 9's or three 6's?"

Comment: It's especially bizarre that he'd say that 11 and 4 is valid because the answerer might not know coin denominations, but then say 10 and 5 is invalid because everyone knows that they're a dime and nickel.

Comment: All else aside, "Is this problem a good puzzle at all?" I'd say no, it's not. [Xkcd puts it better than I could.](https://xkcd.com/169/)

Comment: @Carmeister but the "mathematician" wasn't part of the puzzle, which is just a neat trick that threw me for a moment.

Comment: When my regime comes to power, I will have coins created with denominations 11c, 4c. Just to annoy those mathematicians, and to make change-making fun again.

Comment: The Spanish silver dollar was literally minted with divisions so you could make your own small change by cutting it up into eight pieces, each worth a Real (the dollar was also called the Real de Ocho). One such piece (12.5% of a dollar) was worth both 10 and 15 cents, and the proverbial "two bits" was a quarter. As "buccaneers" (state-approved pirates) preyed largely on Spanish ships, Pieces of Eight entered the vocabulary.

Comment: @BlueHairedMeerkat is actually telling you the truth. Many cranks call themselves mathematicians but are just cranks.

Comment: _"children aren't obliged to know US coin denominations"_, well, I don't know about children, but anyone reading that puzzle is pretty much required to know what a nickel is...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the puzzle had said that neither coin was a nickel, a solution could have consisted of:

> A dime and a [half dime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_dime), a US coin also worth five cents that predates the nickel by 70 years.

But with the puzzle as actually posed, your answer was correct, and the person who responded to you was both rude and wrong. The puzzle was clearly leaving open the possibility that the second coin was a nickel, and it clearly cared about actual US coin denominations, as you correctly pointed out.

Someone's status and profession doesn't make their answer correct; the content of their answer is what really matters.